# Do mice eat fava plants?

Tags: cover-crop, fava-beans

I sowed some fava beans in my raised bed and something is eating the leaves. I have a compost bin next to it that attracts mice so it may be mice eating them but I am not sure if mice eat leaves.  If not, what could it be?  Any thoughts?[image][image]

Comment: https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/829/1894 and image required but mice are omnivores.

Comment: I am not sure about fava beans, but I know mice once ate all my parsley which kinda looked the same as your affected plants.

Comment: No mouse droppings??

Comment: No in the bed but I see mice around and digging holes to hide

Comment: @b.nota what did you do about it?

Comment: @JStorage, what I did about it? I am afraid that I stopped growing parsley... I don't know in what part of the world you live, and which season it is right now over there. Mice behavior can be dependent on season. It might be that the mice will find something else when other plants (food) start to grow.